# What is safer: Wireguard on Router or on Server behind Router

Tags: server, security, vpn, wireguard

I am currently setting up my home server and I was wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages to either of these approaches:

1. Wireguard on Router
2. Server behind Router

Does it even matter at all?

Comment: The better approach is the one that you understand and are able to maintain.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing this diagram; can you make one? on e.g https://draw.io or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the option closest to the internet is always the better one. Catch problems as soon as possible.

"advantages/disadvantes to either approach"

Either will work and it is really just a matter of preference.
The issue is not the method but the configuration of the method. To use wireguard you need to understand wireguard and your router. To use a server you need to understand how firewalls work.

In regards to learning the server option will be the more interesting option.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have both running (one on my OPNSense router, and one on a Raspberry Pi behind that router), so I have a backup in case one becomes unavailable.

Some references I found useful for setting up on the router:

- https://homenetworkguy.com/how-to/configure-wireguard-opnsense/
- https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/wireguard-client.html
- https://old.reddit.com/r/OPNsenseFirewall/comments/rgn1sc/wireguard_clients_cant_access_lan/

Setting up on the Pi is super-easy:

```
$ curl -sL https://install.pivpn.io > install.sh
$ chmod +x install.sh
$ ./install.sh
$ rm install.sh
```

(Make sure you forward the appropriate port on your router to the Pi!)